# How to Connect Model with Controller and View Using Razor Entity Frame work (CRUD) using Mac OS edition of Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, macos, visual-studio-mac-2022

I'm very much begginer  to ASP.net and Just followed a tutorial and created a small web app.I understood the basics  up to creating a  Model in Visual Studio Mac Edition (2022) , However , when I tried to use entity frame work to Link controller and create a view with user interface ,I get null value for **"DB context Class to Use"** field. I don't know how to fix this issue since I'm using Mac edition of Visual Studio. [DB connect Class to Use is Null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSWzn.png)

Following is my code in the Model class

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
namespace WiseTaskMgtSystem.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String UserName { get; set; }
        public String password { get; set; }



        public UserModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

[Model Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdtBf.png)

I would be highly appreciated if someone could assist me on this to solve the issue.

Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

did you add DBcontextin your solution ? take Image from solution explorer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

DbContext is base class for managing database connections and provides functionality for CRUD operations, that is Database related functionality like data access methods to interact with Database.

In Example below `UserProfile` is Table in the Database.

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

// Class UserProfile maps to the Database Table [UserProfile]

[Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```